# Log the time taken by a Thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, stopwatch

I have this piece of code that spawns 6 threads and executes the `GetAverage` method simultaneously on each thread.

```
 var threadFinishEvents = new List<EventWaitHandle>();
 //StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
 for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
 {
      var threadFinish = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
      threadFinishEvents.Add(threadFinish);
      var thread = new Thread(delegate()
                            {
                                GetAverage(userName);
                                threadFinish.Set();
                                //sw.Stop();
                            });
              //sw.Start();
              thread.Start();
 }
 Mutex.WaitAll(threadFinishEvents.ToArray(), threadTimeout);
 long timeElapsed = sw.TimeElapsed();
```

I want to record the time taken by each thread to execute and log it to a database. I read a lot of posts on google that suggested using `Stopwatch`. I have tried adding the `Stopwatch` code (which I have commented out) to the snippet but not sure if this is right. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the **total time**, start the stopwatch before the loop and stop it after the `WaitAll`.

If you need **separate measurements for each thread**, create a separate stopwatch for each thread inside the loop. Put `sw.Start()` at the beginning of your delegate and `sw.Stop()` at the end of the delegate. Put the stopwatches in a List (as you do with the EventWaitHandle) and read the `TimeElapsed` values at the end of your code.

Comment: Where exactly in the code should I make the changes? Can you please help me with it?

Comment: @user1550951: Sure. Which part of my answer is unclear?

Comment: _Put sw.Start() at the beginning of your delegate and sw.Stop() at the end of the delegate. Put the stopwatches in a List (as you do with the EventWaitHandle) and read the TimeElapsed values at the end of your code._  Does that mean I have to put sw.Start() as the first line in my "GetAverage" method?

Comment: @user1550951: I'd put sw.Start() between `delegate() {` and `GetAverage()` and sw.Stop() right after `GetAverage`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities to measure *average time*: measure total time and divide it by number or threads or measure each thread time, sum it and divide by number (but in this case you can have so called *moving average*, which will be available before last thread time is obtained). Which one to use - depends.

### Measure total time

```
var watch = new StopWatch();
watch.Start();
// .. whole job, creating N threads, waiting for all of them to finish
watch.Stop();
var result = watch.Elapsed / N;
```

It will include overhead (a loop time, creating thread, execution of the first thread, etc), but will be more and more accurate the more threads you run.

### Measure each thread time

```
//  inside each thread
var watch = new StopWatch();
watch.Start();
// ... thread job
watch.Stop();
timeX = watch.Elapsed;

// after job is done
Mutex.Wait...
result = (time1 + time2 + ... ) / N;
```

You don't include any overhead, most accurate result. But you have to keep all `timeX`.

### Moving average time

```
//  inside each thread
var watch = new StopWatch();
watch.Start();
// ... thread job
watch.Stop();
result = (_timePrevious + watch.Elapsed) / 2;
_timePrevious = watch.Elapsed;

// after job done
result = result; // total result is the same as the most recent
```

Here we use only 2 measurements (and first value of `result` will be inaccurate, due to uninitialized `_timePrevious`) , but it could be more. You can have a dynamic list to hold *all* times (which makes result most accurate at the end), or, to example, fixed array with moving position (which gets filled by first measurement, but then is updated by new threads).